# Bootstrap 3.0 A Tag Like Button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I upgraded to Bootstrap 3.0. .btn class doesn't effect "a" tag now. And it looks like normal link. What we will do ?

Comment: use a concrete button class (e.g. `btn btn-default`, `btn btn-primary`, ...) see: [Buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it still does.

`<a class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></a>`

See this **[demo](http://jsbin.com/owUKOxI/1/edit?html,output)**

Comment: thank you for your help. it's working. Only syntax is changed.